# Specifying within Xcode dart main entry point

Tags: xcode, flutter

Supporting multiple environments my Flutter app contains multiple main entry point files:

```
main_prod.dart
main_dev.dart
main_staging.dart
```

Within each file importing the appropriate config file:

```
void main() => runApp(
    new ConfigWrapper(config: Config.fromJson(config), child: new PlatterzApp()));
```

Building android APK, I can specify the **main** entry point using command:

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi -t lib/config/main_prod.dart
```

I am searching for a way of archiving this using **Xcode** for iOS app (multiple targets)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to roman's answer, you can also configure the entry points directly from Xcode. Just open your Runner.xcworkspace with XCode, select the 'Runner' project, go to Build Settings and make sure the **all** option is selected (see image in the link below). Then, just type FLUTTER_TARGET at search bar (upper right corner) and edit the dart's entry points.

[image: Dart's entry points in Xcode]

Answer (score 6):

You can use custom xcconfig (like Release.xcconfig or Debug.xcconfig) and override FLUTTER_TARGET property from Generated.xcconfig. E.g. dev.xcconfig:

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
app_name_prefix=DEV.
bundle_id_suffix=.dev
FLUTTER_TARGET=/path/to/your/main_dev.dart
```