# The --dart-define argument is not working until refreshing the app

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use --dart-define but it isn't working.

I have tried `flutter run --dart-define=ENV=Value`

And also this vs code launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dev",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/lib/main_development.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "toolArgs": [
                "--flavor",
                "development",
                "--dart-define",
                "ENV=development",
                "--target",
                "lib/main_development.dart",
                "-v"
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "Qa",
            "program": "lib/main_qa.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "toolArgs": [
                "--flavor",
                "qa",
                "--dart-define",
                "ENV=qa",
                "--target",
                "lib/main_qa.dart",
                "-v"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Then on the first run:

```
const env = String.fromEnvironment('ENV');
```

is always "".

I'm on mac 13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d). I need to do this because iOS seems to run main.dart on the first run, not main_development.dart/main_qa.dart. Waiting 5 seconds does not cause it to work. Hitting refresh causes main_development.dart/main_qa.dart to run, and also `const env = String.fromEnvironment('ENV')` to work.

The issue is not about syntax, because I changed my dev launch settings to @Riyan's answer and kept my qa launch settings the same. And they both work, but only after an app refresh.

I am using both the iOS simulator and physical iOS device. It behaves the same in release mode.

Comment: 'const env = String.fromEnvironment('ENV'); print(env);' like in your snippet gives the correct result for me, both with the VS code config (copied your toolArgs) and with 'flutter run --dart-define ENV=Value'. The additional '=' after dart-define is not how this is typically used.
What OS are you running on? Did you try running on Desktop just to compare? I'm on Windows by the way.

Comment: @FourtyTwo thanks.  I replied in the question to give everyone the info.

Answer (score 3):

Additional to @Riyan answer,

One interesting thing I found lately.

```
print(const String.fromEnvironment('env')); // works
print(String.fromEnvironment('env')); // empty string
```

adding `const` somehow makes it work.

Comment: Thanks however I already have const.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins 
have you tried `const env = const String.fromEnvironment('ENV');`, not just 
`const env = String.fromEnvironment('ENV');`

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins have you found the solution? I am facing the same issue while setting up flavors and env using --dart-define-from-file

Comment: @boonyongyang is your issue in iOS only? I believe my issue ended up being with my ios configuration. The generated config files (e.g. dev.xcconfig) need to have `FLUTTER_TARGET=lib/main_development.dart` in them (swap with the file name of your main file for each environment). [This answer explains how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72552496/3935156).

Answer (score 1):

Found the dart guide for environment variables [environment-declarations](https://dart.dev/guides/environment-declarations)

Code :

```
print(const String.fromEnvironment('env'));
print(const String.fromEnvironment('prod'));
```

CLI:

```
flutter run --dart-define="env=CLI" --dart-define=prod=true
```

[image: CLI output]

Android Studio Run/Debug Configuration:

[image: Run/Debug Configuration]

[image: AS output]

VS Code launch.json:

[image: launch.json]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So should `"--dart-define=env=dev"` in launch.json set it to dev? we don't need `"--dart-define=env=vscode"` eh?  Because it still is not working.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins you can set string to anything, not specified to "dev".
"--dart-define","ENV=development", can you change this to "--dart-define=ENV=development" and run in launch.json?

Comment: Are you on stable channel? It is a timing issue. When I hit the refresh button it is working the second load. This is not good as I need to do this on first load.

Comment: I am using Stable Channel and also on Windows. Also I'm calling the environment variable in main() before runApp().

`void main() {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(const String.fromEnvironment('ENV'));
    print(const String.fromEnvironment('prod'));
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}`

Comment: Okay cool. I kinda replied in the bottom of the question. Both yours and my syntax work. Something is making me have to refresh the app to get a value.

Comment: Okay. sorry, since I do not have Mac available Im not able to replicate this issue, Maybe someone can replicate and solve your question.